# In-app Billing. Пример

Tags: android

Хочу реализовать в приложении In-app Billing.
Знаю, что нужно скопировать себе файл IInAppBillingService.aidl и файлы из "TrivialDrive\app\src\main\java\com\example\android\trivialdrivesample\util\".
Знаю, что нужен код(ключ) из гугл плей консоли.
Знаю, что нужно использовать методы из примера. Но какие именно и каким образом?
Про эту ссылку тоже знаю:
https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html?hl=ru#Connect

Нужен пример кода покупки PRO-функционала. Например во Free-версии imageView1 скрыт(INVISIBLE), а после оплаты становится: imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Т.е. примерно так:
1. В переменную "x" записываем код(ключ).
2. Берем метод "method1".. добавляем его в onCreate.
3. Берем метод "method2".. добавляем его в onCreate.. в нем реализуем "imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);"
4. Ну и другие методы, какие требуются.

@Hombre
Делаю так:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler {

    ImageView imageView1;
    BillingProcessor bp;
    private final static String KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        bp = new BillingProcessor(this, KEY, this);

        // Далее надо что-то здесь писать?
    }


    @Override
    public void onBillingInitialized() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProductPurchased(@NonNull String productId, @Nullable TransactionDetails details) {
        imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // Показываю imageView1 если совершена покупка. Правильно?
    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingError(int errorCode, @Nullable Throwable error) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {

    }

    // Для чего переопределять?
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (!bp.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (bp != null) {
            bp.release();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    // Нажатие кнопки "Купить Pro-версию"
    public void buttonBuy (View view) {
        bp.purchase(this, "pro_version_code"); //Правильно?
    }

}
```

Покупка совершается, но при последующем запуске, приложение работает в режиме Free-версии. Если нажать кнопку купить, то начинает работать как Pro-версия.

"Также не забудьте проверить список купленных товаров по loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle." - для чего это?

Просто мне не очень понятен сам механизм процессов...
Как приложение понимает, что оно уже куплено и надо работать как Pro-версия?
Как происходит проверка?
А если нет интернета?

Comment: Советую вам отказаться от вашей реализации скрытия изображений. Дело в том, что такой способ очень легко поддается взлому, необходимо просто сделать реверс-инжиринг вашего приложения, поменять видимость картинки и все! Лучшим решением будет загрузка картинки с вашего сервера и подтверждение покупки тоже на отдельном сервере.

Comment: Сомнительный совет, во-первых далеко не легко разобрать и собрать апкашку, если хоть каплю знаете про прогуард. Вы в целом видели как проекты с хорошей обфускацией выглядят при разборе? А во вторых вы получаете ttansactionDetail в рантайме , и даже если вы магическим образом сделаете задуманное, то при пробросе purchase во время нажатия в ответ получите кукиш, ибо вы не имеете полученных деталей покупки. Уже не говоря что в биллинг арт можно создать кастомные секьюрити менеджеры, ток это более низкий уровень.

Comment: Там все разжевано и есть ссылка на пример реализации. Если нет интернета то список покупок все равно хранится. https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую присмотреться к библиотеке https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3.

Пример реализации:

Добавьте в `implements` активности/фрагмента `BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler`, после чего автоматически реализуйте требуемые методы `onBillingInitialized, onProductPurchased, onBillingError, onPurchaseHistoryRestored`.

Далее в `onCreate/onViewCreated`:

```
bp = new BillingProcessor(this, "Ключ из консоли разработчика для покупок", this);
```

Методы совершения покупок и проверки уже купленных товаров есть на странице библиотеки. Все очень просто.

Comment: А дальше? Как мне вызвать диалог покупки? "bp.consumePurchase("YOUR PRODUCT ID FROM GOOGLE PLAY CONSOLE HERE");" Так? Куда вставлять мой код "imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);" ?

Comment: @Рома событие onProductPurchased вызывается после успешной покупки, в нем и делайте что душе угодно. Также не забудьте проверить список купленных товаров по loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle. Вообще, все очень доступно расписано на странице библиотеки.